# How can I see the `yarn install` log when deploy node app to gcp cloudfunction

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have read this doc https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs which says `The Cloud Functions Node.js runtimes generally support installing using npm or yarn.`. I expect `cloud function` does a `yarn install` when I deploy the function to GCP.

Where can I find the log of `yarn install`?

How do I know which version of `yarn` or `npm` does it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a cloud functions (or an app engine service, it's the same thing) a cloud build is trigger to build a container based on your code (thanks to BuildPack which detect automatically your language and the corresponding layer to build the container).

Of course, you view nothing of that, except the logs in Cloud Builds. Have a look to the build history and to the logs on each to view the container construction and the step status. *You might view the yarn version, I never used it, I can't confirm*